# Add new div to each div

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with a testdome task.

Function appendChildren should add a new child div to each existing div. New divs should be decorated by calling decorateDiv.

For example, after appendChildren is executed, the following divs:

```
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
  </div>
</div>
```

should take the following form (assuming decorateDiv does nothing):

```
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

The code below should do the job, but for some reason it goes into an infinite loop. I can't see the bugs. Can some explain whats wrong here?

```
function appendChildren(decorateDiv) {
  var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

  for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    decorateDiv(newDiv);
    allDivs[i].appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}

 
document.body.innerHTML = `
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
  </div>
</div>`;

 
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are editing an array while looping through that array, thats a big no no.
what you would want to do is create a copy of the array, iterate through the original while editing the copy, then replace the original with its copy.

(imagine iterating through something that keeps getting larger and larger... the more you edit it, the larger it becomes...)

Comment: he is not editing an array but an `HTML collection object` which is "only" an array-like object.

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelectorAll` and irritate the Node List with `forEach`. Then add a `div` at the inside end of the element with `insertAdjacentHTML` and use the param `beforeend`.

Also, use an EventListener to wait for a `DOMContentLoaded` to only run that function once at start:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let ele = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  ele.forEach(el =>
    el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div></div>')
  );
  
  console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
})
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a live node list, so as you add divs, `allDivs` reflects those changes. You could possibly cache `allDivs.length` by saving it to a variable `divCount` then use `for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i++) {...}`

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` does not return a `Node List` but an `HTML collection object`.  `querySelectorAll` returns a `Node List`.

Answer (score 0):

If new div won't have id, then you can just change the way you get `allDivs` as parents:

```
var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div[id]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are placing allDivs inside the appendChild() function. When you call the appendChild() function, allDivs is created. However, when the function ends, it discards the variable allDivs. Another thing I should mention is that when allDivs variable is being created, it gets updated with a new value node list, because document.getElementsByTagName() returns all the elements that has the tag . The reason why the variable is updating is because each time the function is called, the loop will insert more divs. To fix this problem, place the allDivs variable outside the function so that it will stay the same when the function is called.